# Learning Windows Workflow Foundation 4, where to start?

Tags: iis-7, recommendation-engine, workflow-foundation-4, appfabric

I have been playing around with wf4 for a while. I found various articles, videos(channel 9), blog posts and sites about wf4, but couldn't able to organize it in a proper way.

I look forward to create a Learning Catalog for

- Windows Workflow 4 with VS 2010 and IIS 7 (without AppFabric )
- Windows Workflow 4 with VS 2010 and IIS 7 (with AppFabric)

Please help me to create it...
post your answers

- where to start?
- what to learn first?
- must learn topics - in the order of importance
- publishing as WCF Service
- hosting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Windows Workflow Foundation Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/netframework/aa663328(en-us).aspx) is a good place to start.

And if you want to take a course go [here](http://www.develop.com/training-course/workflow-4.0) (shameless self plug)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend a great book by Bruce Bukovics ["Pro WF"](http://www.apress.com/book/view/9781430227212) (rewritten for WF4). Also check Microsoft's Ron Jacobs online video series.